# I want to get latitude longitude height of my mouse at the bottom of the cesium screen

Tags: javascript, location, cesiumjs

For now using below javascript, I am getting the lat long values over the mouse pointer. How can I make it appear at the bottom of the cesium screen like it is in google earth.

```
viewer.entities.add({
    id: 'mou',
    label: {
        // position : Cesium.Cartesian2.ZERO, 
        show: true;
    }
});
viewer.scene.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var entity = viewer.entities.getById('mou');
    var ellipsoid = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid;
    // Mouse over the globe to see the cartographic position 
    var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(new Cesium.Cartesian3(e.clientX, e.clientY), ellipsoid);
    if (cartesian) {
        var cartographic = ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(cartesian);
        var longitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude).toFixed(10);
        var latitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude).toFixed(10);
        entity.position = cartesian;
        entity.label.show = true;
        entity.label.font_style = 84;
        //entity.position= Cesium.Cartesian2.ZERO; 
        entity.label.text = '(' + longitudeString + ', ' + latitudeString + ')';
        var result = latitudeString(45);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    } else {
        entity.label.show = false;
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the styling on that `demo` element you reference near the bottom?  Seems like you could place that at the bottom of your Cesium window with a bit of CSS, and you could get rid of the `entity` and its label entirely.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you are perhaps running this in Sandcastle? In this case the sites styling makes it a bit difficult to add additional divs.  But if you position them absolutely and give a high z-index, you can make the div appear on top of the CesiumViewer container.

Additionally, there were a few  problems with a misplaced semicolon inside the entity "mou" label object. And you tried to use the latitudeString as a function call.

[Working SandCastle link](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html#c=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)

**HTML**

```
<style>
    @import url(../templates/bucket.css);
</style>
<div id="demo" style="z-index: 2000; position: absolute; height:100px; width:200px; right: 10px; bottom: 0px; text-color: white"></div>

<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
viewer.entities.add({
    id: 'mou',
    label: {
        // position : Cesium.Cartesian2.ZERO, 
        show: true   // Removed semicolon here
    }
});
viewer.scene.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    var entity = viewer.entities.getById('mou');
    var ellipsoid = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid;
    // Mouse over the globe to see the cartographic position 
    var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(new Cesium.Cartesian3(e.clientX, e.clientY), ellipsoid);
    if (cartesian) {
        var cartographic = ellipsoid.cartesianToCartographic(cartesian);
        var longitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude).toFixed(10);
        var latitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude).toFixed(10);
        entity.position = cartesian;
        entity.label.show = true;
        entity.label.font_style = 84;
        //entity.position= Cesium.Cartesian2.ZERO; 
        entity.label.text = '(' + longitudeString + ', ' + latitudeString + ')';
        var result = entity.label.text;  // We can reuse this
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    } else {
        entity.label.show = false;
    }
});
```